# How can I indent my code in a git repo and commit and merge without history?

Tags: git, gitlab

I have a git repo with so many C language code files, which are bad formatted.

So can I use indent tool to reformat my source files, and commit them and push it to gitlab repo without changing the history?

Of course normal commit and push and PR workflow works, but the most recent history of each file will be destoried and display one same message.

Thanks.

Comment: “but the most recent history of each file will be destoried” how so?

Comment: @matt, by changing the latest displayed commit message on GitLab to the reformat one. Which is how the system is intended to work. The short answer to your question is no. You cannot without properly destroying the repo history. Once created, a commit is immutable.

Comment: I don't get it. Reformatting is a change. It is a historical fact. What is so wrong with having that fact be a commit. Whether or not the commit _says_ "reformatted", the reformatting will be there in the history. It doesn't ruin the history, it _is_ the history. You cannot pretend it isn't, unless you want to go back and rewrite all the files in all the commits.

Comment: Yes of course reformatting is the history because it changes the source files. But actually it does not actually change every single logic or algorithm in those source files so that maybe we could consider it not a really history. And also, thanks to all. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you can't make those changes without changing the history, you can make those changes and put them in an existing commit.

`git commit --amend` will add any staged changes to the most recent commit on the current branch.

The commit message will remain the same but the commit hash will change.

In order to push an amended commit you need to provide the `-f` flag to force your changes to the remote repository, since the hash changed. (Be careful with force pushes, if anyone else has pushed to the repository since you last pulled their changes will be erased.)